# Unable to Resolve Library Activity for Android Test

Tags: android

I created a very basic Android-Maven-project using [Android-Release Archetype](http://stand.spree.de/wiki_details_maven_archetypes). The one thing I changed was setting the Android project to an Android library. This means I have no *AndroidManifest* defining the activities. The Maven build still works for the `HelloAndroidActivity` and `HelloAndroidActivityTest`, but even copying both classes will make the new test fail:

> Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=org.acme.project.android/.HelloAndroidActivity2}

I've searched the entire workspace and could not find any reference to `HelloAndroidActivity` that would explain why it works with that activity but not with this one.  So I guess I have two questions: Why does the integration test work with an activity that is not referenced in any manifest file? And why doesn't it work for an identical copy of this activity?

I don't think it matters much, but these are my *AndroidManifests*:

Library project:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="org.acme.project.android"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0-SNAPSHOT" >

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    </manifest>
```

Integration test project:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="org.acme.project.android.test"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0-SNAPSHOT" >

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
        </application>

        <instrumentation
            android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
            android:targetPackage="org.acme.project.android" />
    </manifest>
```

---

Without changing a thing I'm getting today:

> [2014-06-09 08:39:47 - org.acme.project.android.it] Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'

There is no additional informtion at all, not even which class is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. I assume only the last step should be necessary, but in my case it didn't work until after I proceed the entire ordeal:

1. I set the package of the integration test project to `org.acme.project.android` (i.e. removed `.test`) - this made Eclipse able to execute the tests
2. I added the `.test` again, because Maven didn't like the to R files in one package (`IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/acme/project/android/R`)
3. (at this point, all changes were reverted) I added the activities to the integration test manifest

As I said, the first two steps should be stupid, but I've added and removed the activities a hundred times to various manifest files all over the place, and it never worked. So maybe the thorough cleaning and building after the package change was all it needed to make the changes visible.